# How to get latest record using Pivot in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Can you please tell me how to achieve this?

```
ColumnName- 1.ID     2.attribute_name   3.attribute_value   4.Date   
           1         attr1              val1            28-07-2017   
           1         attr1              val2           29-07-2017 Latest record
           2         attr1              val1           28-07-2017    
           2         attr2              val2           29-07-2017 Latest record
           2         attr2              val3           30-07-2017    
           3         attr1              val1           30-07-2017 Latest record
```

and Output should be like below,

```
ID attribute_name attribute_value
1       attr1          val2 
2       attr1          val1 
2       attr2          val3
3       attr1          val1
```

Only I need latest value for each attribute respective with ID & Dates.

Comment: Post the original pivot query. We can do the filtration in source itself

Comment: Is McGrady's edit correct with regard to ouput?  You flag pivot, but this suggests no pivot.  That having been said, I applaud McGrady for turning a totally unreadable question into something meaningful!

Comment: @JonathanWillcock - I guess sample data is result of a `pivot` query

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `Row_Number`

```
Select * from 
(
select *,Row_NUmber()Over(Partition by ID, attribute_name order by [Date] desc) as Rn
From yourtable
) a
Where Rn = 1
```

but as I mentioned in comments If you post the original pivot query, we can do the filtration in source itself